# Fetch user full data from mysql database by scanning the "user id" as "QR" code in flutter

Tags: flutter

How Can I Retrieve A "users full details", by scanning as just the user id in Flutter,,From my php Mysql Database.

```
Like..
id: **12345**,
User Name: John
Cell: 24245621
Language: English
```

when I'll sacn `QR(qr value=**12345**[which is John's id])`, then instantly from Mysql database, the output will be like..

```
User Name: John
Cell: 24245621
Language: English
```

Can anyone share the idea,code/any please
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use barcode_scan package: `https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan` to scan QR code
and use qr_flutter package to generate qr : `https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter`

Comment: @Raihanpial those package can help you with your problem

Comment: u need to first generate the barcodes for ur all your ids

Comment: refer barcode_scan package, about scanning. Once u scan the barcode, you'll get the scanned result and depending on the result u can run query to fetch the details from the database